# place Rounded Uiimageview randomly but not overlapping within the screen (not off the screen)

Tags: objective-c

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.size.height/2;
```

I have this perfectly rounded UIImageviews. 
I just want to place them randomly, not off the screen and not overlapping each other as well.

How can i do that??

When i round the UIImageView with the code above and write code like 
currentImageView is current ImageView on superView and new Frame is new Fram picked randomly. Does this code work for round UIImageView?

```
BOOL interRect = CGRectIntersectsRect(currentImageView.frame, newFrame);
```

Or How can i place them randomly, not off the screen and not overlapping each other as well??

Comment: If they're truly circular, then `CGRectIntersectsRect` is too conservative. You can do `hypotf` from the `center` of one to the `center` of the other, and see if that's less than the sum of the radius of the two rounded views.

Comment: When i round the UIIMageView like that, the whole boundary of the View is round right??

Comment: Not really. The view is still rectangular, but the corners are masked, so you can't see them, but they're actually still there. `CGRectIntersectsRect` works with rectangular views, but doesn't care if the corners have been masked away and aren't visible.

Comment: Then is it the same when i add code like [self setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]; and add circular image to the UIImageView. The boundary is still rectangle??

Comment: Just one more question, does the masked corners are invisible when they are overlapped with another UIImageView??

Comment: The masked corner is invisible even over another UIImageView right? I just tested it haha but just want to make sure ha

Comment: There is no "boundary" for standard `UIView` subclasses. You have `frame`, which is `CGRect`. But don't worry about intersection of the frames, but rather just worry whether the visible portion of the views appear to overlap (i.e. if the distance between the two centers, eg `hypotf`, are less than the sum of their respective radius values). And yes, because the corners are transparent, even if the `frame` values overlap, if only the masked corners overlap, it will "look" like they don't overlap.

Comment: If the masked views aren't completely circular, though, the math is more complicated. But there are tricks to get around that, if needed. But if truly circular, checking the distance between the centers is easiest.